# hyphenated noun

Tags: nouns, hyphenation

I am proofreading a text and I am not sure if I should hyphenate the following noun.

We are considering limits in which, without going into details, something happens to different objects, A1, A2, A3, etc... We want to refer to the limit where something happens to e.g. A1 as the *A1 limit*. Should it be hyphenated, i.e. the *A1-limit*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think hyphen use for compounds is predictable -- you'd need a style guide of some sort listing approved hyphenated forms.  If you are are coining a new compound, consequently, which is probably the case with your example, you should never use a hyphen, because your compound could not be on such a list.